# How to get Number Of Rows in a table MySQL version 4 without using count(*) query?

Tags: mysql

I Know how to get Number Of Rows in a table  in MySQL 5 version and later.

MySQL 5

`select table_rows from tables where table_name = 'tableName';`

I want to know how to get this in MySQL 4  because count(*) query takes to 4 to 5 minutes in large tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*)` tells the database engine to still iterate over the individual fields or each record. Since you only care about the raw number of rows, you can try @dj2's suggestion and do

> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM <TableName>

But I wonder if you get any better performance by counting on the primary key by querying over your clustered index.

> SELECT COUNT(<PrimaryKey>) FROM <TableName>

Comment: you can also just do: select count(1) from <tablename>

Answer (score 0):

**INFORMATION_SCHEMA** which contains **table_rows** is not available for MySql 4.0. Your best bet will be to optimize your **count()** by  doing a **count()** on indexed key.

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks all for your response . I want to generate schema analyzing report . It will travel all schema and get table count  to generate that report . I dont know which column is the primary key (or) which column is indexed .